# Two default routes with same metric

Tags: centos, route, iproute, nmcli, gateway

Using `NetworkManager` on CentOS 7.6 I was able to create two default routes with same metric:

```
# nmcli connection eth0 modify ipv4.route-metric 10
# nmcli connection eth1 modify ipv4.route-metric 10
# nmcli connection up eth0
# nmcli connection up eth1
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 10 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 10
```

That's looking strange to me because I thought there possible only one default route with specific metric and if I try to achieve same routing table with `ip` I've got an error:

```
# sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp metric 11
# sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 11
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

So basically I have two questions:

1) Is that a bug? If it's not how kernel interpret such a routing table?

2) How can I build such a routing table using `ip` command?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo ip route append default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 11
```

note that `append` is used instead of `add`.

Comment: It's still meaningless to have two default routes with the same metric. Think for a moment what the _default_ route is for

Comment: Multiple routes (default or otherwise) do indeed have a use - what if you're on a remote network with two links to the main network. Why not have a default route that can utilise both links simultaneously?