# Two default routes with same metric: which one will Linux kernel use

Tags: linux, networking

Similar questions but no answer:

- [Two default routes with same metric](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533771/two-default-routes-with-same-metric)
- [How does Linux choose between default gateways?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337332/how-does-linux-choose-between-default-gateways)

On Linux, when two routes have the same metric, which one will be used? I found this is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc779696(v=ws.10)) for Windows ("If multiple interfaces of the same speed have the same lowest interface metric, then, based upon the binding order, the default gateway of the first network adapter is used. The default gateway for the second network adapter is used when the first is unavailable.") but cannot find how Linux is handling this.

I guess the answer is in the [code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/route.c) but it's not obvious.

Comment: AFAIK it's undefined, so even if you find out how it works for a particular Linux version, you shouldn't rely on that staying the same ... so just don't use default routes with the same metric. If this is an XY question, and you want to do load balancing on several gateways: There are ways to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The Kernel does not allow you to have multiple equally viable routes. It will reject the second route with an `EEXIST` error:

```
% ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 metric 10
% echo $?
0
% ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 dev eth1 metric 10
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
% echo $?
2
```

You can have a multipath route, i.e. a single route with multiple nexthops, in which the Kernel will distribute (load sharing/load balancing) traffic among the available nexthops according to the [`fib_multipath_hash_policy`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/ip-sysctl.html):

```
% ip route add 192.0.2.0/24 metric 10 nexthop dev eth0 nexthop dev eth1
% ip route show to exact 192.0.2.0/24
192.0.2.0/24 metric 10
        nexthop dev eth0 weight 1
        nexthop dev eth1 weight 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having two (or more) default routes.  This is simple enough when using static IP addressing.  Just don't put anything into the "gateway" field.  If you're using DHCP-assigned addresses, you could reconfigure the DHCP server to only advertise one default route, or configure you're Linux machine to ignore one of the default routes.  I routinely do the later with a simple NetworkManager command, like this:

```
$ nmcli connection modify "eth1" ipv4.ignore-auto-routes yes
```